# LINQ to XML DOM (making a modifed Tree easily)

Tags: c#, xml, linq, xmldom

I'd like to delete the last element and put somthing else instead of it.

I made some imaginary codes (** IT IS NOT Working one**).

I want to re-use upper part of it, because they are too long and changing all the time.

How can I make real ones ?

Thanks !!

```
var orignalTREE = new XDocument(
    new XElement( "Root", new XAttribute("Id", "0"),
        new XElement( "One", new XAttribute("Id", "1"),
            new XElement( "Two", new XAttribute("Id", "2"),
                new XElement( "Three", new XAttribute("Id", "3"),
                    new XElement( "Four", new XAttribute("Id", "4"),
                        new XElement( "Five", new XAttribute("Id", "5"),
                            new XElement("Six", new XAttribute("Id", "6"),
                                new XElement("Seven", new XAttribute("Id", "7"),
                                    new XElement( "LAST", "It will be removed")
)))))))));

var extractedELMNT = orignalTREE.ElementsBeforeSelf("LAST");
orignalTREE.Descendants("LAST").Remove();

var modifiedTREE = new XDocument(
    new XElement(
        extractedELMNT.Select(x =>x),
            new XElement( "Modified", new XAttribute("Testing...")
)));
MessageBox.Show( "Removed\n\n" + orignalTREE.ToString() +"\n\n\n"+ 
                 "Recovered\n\n" + modifiedTREE.ToString());
```

[Add]

I'd like to change the result from This one;

```
<Root Id="0">
    <One Id="1">
        <Two Id="2">
            <Three Id="3">
                <Four Id="4">
                    <Five Id="5">
                        <Six Id="6">
                            <Seven Id="7">
                                <LAST>It will be removed</LAST>
                            </Seven>
                        </Six>
                    </Five>
                </Four>
            </Three>
        </Two>
    </One>
</Root>
```

to This one.

```
<Root Id="0">
    <One Id="1">
        <Two Id="2">
            <Three Id="3">
                <Four Id="4">
                    <Five Id="5">
                        <Six Id="6">
                            <Seven Id="7">
                                <Modified>Testing..</Modified>
                            </Seven>
                        </Six>
                    </Five>
                </Four>
            </Three>
        </Two>
    </One>
</Root>
```

In general ways.

Comment: What is the actual requirment?

Comment: I added some contents. From "this" to "this". I think it could be the answer to your comment.

Comment: is it always the `Id="7"` node you want to add to? Can't you extract that node and add elements to it?

Comment: @Default Yap. yap.. the "Id =7" is solid, it is not changing. But, its Descendants are changing all the time. Thanks.

Comment: oh, so you want different trees where it always starts the same, like a template of some kind?

Comment: @Default Right. Yes. Most of the contents are the same (exactly same), but some elemets are deleted (and added).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:
**Updated:**

```
var orignalTREE = new XDocument(
            new XElement("Root", new XAttribute("Id", "0"),
                new XElement("One", new XAttribute("Id", "1"),
                    new XElement("Two", new XAttribute("Id", "2"),
                        new XElement("Three", new XAttribute("Id", "3"),
                            new XElement("Four", new XAttribute("Id", "4"),
                                new XElement("Five", new XAttribute("Id", "5"),
                                    new XElement("Six", new XAttribute("Id", "6"),
                                        new XElement("Seven", new XAttribute("Id", "7"),
                                            new XElement("LAST", "It will be removed")
                                            )))))))));

        var modifiedTREE = new XDocument(orignalTREE);
        var parent = modifiedTREE.Descendants("LAST").FirstOrDefault().Parent;
        modifiedTREE.Descendants("LAST").Remove();
        parent.Add(new XElement("Modified", "Its attribute"));

        Console.WriteLine("Removed\n\n" + orignalTREE.ToString() + "\n\n\n" +
                          "Recovered\n\n" + modifiedTREE.ToString());
```